# How to create a map in Appcelerator Titanium

Tags: appcelerator

How to create a map in Appcelerator Titanium where it shows the position of the user until it closes the application, then save it?

Answer (score 4):

Well, it seems that you did not even bother to check out on internet before asking question here. :)

But here's the way you can use inbuilt maps in Titanium apps.

You need to follow this **[Titanium Map Module](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Modules.Map)** for configuring the maps for iOS/Android.

There are pretty clear examples there on this link.

Now, 2nd part of your query is that how you save it when user closes the app. It's different for Android & iOS because on Android you can also close the app by pressing back button.

You can follow this approach for both platform:

- Create a timeout function which will keep detecting the user's current location
- Save this location in local app data using Ti.App.Properties methods.

This approach will work on iOS & Android both & you do not need to write any extra code for back button press handling on Android.